# Erlport/Python STDOUT capture to Elixir

Tags: python, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, gen-server

I'm trying to pipe STDOUT from Python/Erlport back to Elixir. I've got `:python` calls working fine, I just want to send the STDOUT stuff from Python back to Elixir for logging but I can't wrap my head around how to achieve that. I know it's [possible](http://erlport.org/docs/python.html#standard-output-redirection) even though I'm using Python 2.7.

I've got a Genserver wrapper around the `:python` module so that my call works like so:

```
pid = Python.start()
Python.call(pid, :bridge, :register_handler, [self()])
```

Python.call just looks like this:

```
def call(pid, module, function, args \\ []) do
  :python.call(pid, module, function, args)
end
```

Anything from `:bridge` (i.e., `bridge.py`) is lost to STDOUT unless I explicitly return something (obviously halting the function). What can I do to capture STDOUT?

My idea was to call something like `Python.call(pid, :builtins, :print, [self()])` but that results in a bunch of errors and I really don't know if that's the right direction at all.

I actually want to pipe it into a Phoenix channel, but that's the easy part (I hope). Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else getting stuck with this kinda thing: since I've got a GenServer around the `:python` instance, I've just leveraged `handle_info`:

```
def handle_info({:python, message}, session) do
  message |> String.split("\n", trim: true)
  SomeWeb.Endpoint.broadcast("log", "update", %{body: message})

  {:stop, :normal,  session}
end
```

**Detail**

To more fully outline my solution as @7stud advised, I'll include the wider approach based on `erlport` and [this great post](https://hackernoon.com/mixing-python-with-elixir-ii-async-e8586f9b2d53). Accordingly, I've got a `Python` module that looks like this:

```
defmodule App.Python do
   @doc """
      Python instance pointing to priv/python.
    """
   def start() do
      path = [
         :code.priv_dir(:prefect),
         "python"
      ]|> Path.join()

      {:ok, pid} = :python.start([
         {:python_path, to_charlist(path)}
      ])
      pid
   end

   def call(pid, module, function, args \\ []) do
      :python.call(pid, module, function, args)
   end

   def cast(pid, message) do
      :python.cast(pid, message)
   end

   def stop(pid) do
      :python.stop(pid)
   end
end
```

It's called from a GenServer that handles its spawning and termination:

```
defmodule App.PythonServer do
   @doc """
      Receives async. messages from Python instance.
    """
   use GenServer

   alias App.Python

   def start_link() do
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
   end

   def init(_args) do
      pid = Python.start()
      Python.call(pid, :bridge, :register_handler, [self()])
      App.Application.broadcast_change

      {:ok, pid}
   end

   def cast_draw(id) do
      {:ok, pid} = start_link()

      GenServer.cast(pid, {:id, id})
   end

   def call_draw(id) do
      {:ok, pid} = start_link()

      GenServer.call(pid, {:id, id}, 10_000)
   end

   def handle_call({:id, id}, _from, session) do
      result = Python.call(session, :bridge, :draw, [id])

      {:reply, result, session}
   end

   def handle_cast({:id, id}, session) do
      Python.cast(session, id)

      {:noreply, session}
   end

   def handle_info({:python, message}, session) do
      msg = message |> format_response
      {:ok, time} = Timex.now |> Timex.format("{h12}:{m}{am} {D}/{M}/{YYYY}")
      AppWeb.Endpoint.broadcast("log", "update", %{time: time, body: msg, process: message})

      {:stop, :normal,  session}
   end

   def terminate(_reason, session) do
      Python.stop(session)
      App.Application.broadcast_change

      :ok
   end

   defp format_response(message) do
      if String.contains? message, "[result] Sent" do
         message |> String.split("\n", trim: true) |> Enum.at(-2)
      else
         message |> String.split("\n", trim: true) |> Enum.take(-12) |> Enum.join("\n")
      end
   end
end
```

You can see at the end if STDOUT doesn't return a certain string from `bridge.py` (or any other Python module) it'll return a stacktrace. Speaking of, `bridge.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

from erlport.erlang import set_message_handler, cast
from erlport.erlterms import Atom

message_handler = None # reference to the elixir process to send

cmd = "xvfb-run -a python"
py = os.path.join("/home/ubuntu/app/priv/python/export.py")

def cast_message(pid, message):
  cast(pid, message)

def register_handler(pid):
  global message_handler
  message_handler = pid

def handle_message(id):
    try:
      result = draw(id)
      print result
      if message_handler:
        cast_message(message_handler, (Atom('python'), result))
    except Exception, error:
      print error
      if message_handler:
        cast_message(message_handler, (Atom('python'), error))
      pass

def draw(id):
  proc = subprocess.check_output(
    "{0} {1} {2}".format(cmd, py, id), stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True
  )
  return proc

set_message_handler(handle_message)
```

Answer (score 2):

> My idea was to call something like `Python.call(pid, :builtins,
>   :print, [self()])` but that results in a bunch of errors and I really
>   don't know if that's the right direction at all.

`self()` is not where the output goes--rather `self()` is the argument for `print`, i.e. what python will print out.

I think `erlport` can only handle MFA calls(module, function, argument), and because `print` isn't a function in `python 2.7`, I think you need to wrap a function around `print`, e.g.:

myprint.py:

```
def print_this(str):
    print str
```

> I just want to send the STDOUT stuff from Python back to Elixir for
>   logging but I can't wrap my head around how to achieve that. I know
>   it's possible even though I'm using Python 2.7

The [erlport](http://erlport.org/docs/python.html#standard-output-redirection) docs say:

> As a convenient feature ErlPort also supports redirection of Python`s
>   STDOUT to Erlang...

That appears to be the default setup, so you don't have to do anything to get python stdout to be redirected to elixir stdout.  The question then becomes: "How do you log elixir stdout to a file?"

I'm able to log elixir `stdout` to a file like this:

friends.ex:

```
defmodule Friends do

  use Export.Python

  def go do

    #Get path to logfile:

    priv_path = :code.priv_dir(:friends)
    logfile_path = Path.join([priv_path, "log", "mylog.log"])

    #Redirect stdout:

    {:ok, io_pid} = File.open(logfile_path, [:append])
    Process.group_leader(self(), io_pid)

    #Send output to stdout:

    IO.puts "Am I in the log file??!"

    python_path = Path.expand("lib/python") 
    {:ok, py} = Python.start(
                 python: "python2.7",
                 python_path: python_path
               )

    Python.call(py, "myprint", "print_this", ["hello world!"])
    Python.call(py, "myprint", "print_this", ["goodbye..."])

    Python.stop(py)
  end

end
```

This is my directory structure:

```
friends
    /lib
      /friends
      /python
          myprint.py
      friends.ex
   /priv
      /log
          mylog.log
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs/friends$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> Friends.go
iex(2)>
```

In the log file:

```
Am I in the log file??!
hello world!
goodbye...
[33m[36m:ok[0m[33m[0m
```

(I don't know what that junk is on the last line.  Edit: Hmmm...it's the atom `:ok` surrounded by some other stuff.)

If I comment out everything inside `go()` above the python_path line, then I get:

```
iex(1)> Friends.go
hello world!
goodbye...
:ok
```

In erlang/elixir file I/O is handled by starting a process to which requests are sent to either write to the file or read the file.  I think stdout gets sent to whatever process is the `group_leader`, and if the process handling file I/O is the group_leader, then stdout gets sent to the file.

I don't know if messing with the `group_leader` will screw things up when you are using a `GenServer`.  There is a warning in the [erlang docs](https://erldocs.com/21.0/erts/erlang.html?i=1&search=group_le#group_leader/2):

> The group leader should be rarely changed in applications with a
>   supervision tree, because OTP assumes the group leader of their
>   processes is their application master.

.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer. I'll mark it as accepted since it definitely explains thing better than my ad-hoc approach.

Comment: @cd-rum, Ah, don't do that.  In your answer, you said, *I've got a Genserver around the :python instance,*--I think it would be helpful if you showed how you set that up.  I recently used a GenServer to get around a similar type of problem.  In my case, a process called a function which made that process the owner of a socket, which meant that only that process could send and receive messages from a socket.  I used a GenServer's `handle_call()` to call the function, which meant that the GenServer became the owner, and messages from the socket were handled by `handle_info()`.

Comment: Fair, I'll expand on my answer shortly.

Comment: @cd-rum, Okay, I edited my answer which means you can remove the checkmark, and when you expand your answer, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: *I don't know what that junk is on the last line. Edit: Hmmm...it's the atom :ok surrounded by some other stuff.)* -- The "other stuff" consists of color codes which are interpreted by the terminal.  `:ok` would display in blue (or something) in the terminal.